# Spark-scala code error while applying unix_timestamp

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying some basic steps in spark-shell with df

I am getting an error for the second statement. can someone explain to me why I am getting the result

```
scala> stagingDF.select("a_ingestion_dtm").show(2,false)
       +--------------------------+
       |a_ingestion_dtm           |
       +--------------------------+
       |2019-07-08 16:10:02.836005|
       |2019-07-08 16:10:02.866005|
       +--------------------------+
      only showing top 2 rows
```

```
  scala> stagingDF.select("a_ingestion_dtm",unix_timestamp(col("a_ingestion_dtm"))).show(10,false)
  <console>:47: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
  cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
          stagingDF.select("a_ingestion_dtm",unix_timestamp(col    ("a_ingestion_dtm"))).show(10,false)
```

Comment: Before `"a_ingestion_dtm"` this column you have to add `$` or `'` symbol to spark consider as a column.  for `unix_timestamp` you specified `col` function.

Comment: stagingDF.select($"time",unix_timestamp(col("time"))).show

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below answer.

```
scala> res11.show
+--------------------+
|                time|
+--------------------+
|2019-07-08 16:10:...|
|2019-07-08 16:10:...|
+--------------------+


scala> res11.select('time, unix_timestamp($"time")).show
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|                time|unix_timestamp(time, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)|
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|2019-07-08 16:10:...|                               1562582402|
|2019-07-08 16:10:...|                               1562582402|
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```